# Why does "pi" become symbolic in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

In the Matlab command window I type:

```
syms f;
s = 2*pi*f*j;
s
```

which returns

```
s =

pi*f*2*j
```

Why is `pi` is not calculated as 3.141592...?What's wrong with the code I entered into the command window?

Comment: Because 3.141592 is not equal to pi.

Comment: Then s is just s= pi*f*2*j ??? what if i want to set f, pi and get s as a number?

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to symbolic math where you get exact answers as opposed to floating-point approximations. If you just want to "get a number" you can use non-symbolic functions and operations or you can convert symbolic results back to floating-point.

For example:

```
syms f
s = pi*f*2*j
s2 = subs(s,f,2)
s3 = double(s2)
```

Alternatively, you can use variable precision arithmetic to represent `pi` as a decimal approximation of a specified level in a symbolic expression:

```
syms f
s = vpa(pi)*f*j
```

See the [documentation for `vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) for further details. You can also use the [`sym`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html) function to achieve similar things.

However, you can lose some of the power of symbolic math if you convert to a decimal or floating point representation too soon. For example, compare the difference between the following expressions:

```
sin(pi)      % 1.224646799147353e-16
sin(vpa(pi)) % -3.2101083013100396069547145883568e-40
sin(sym(pi)) % 0, sin(sym(1)*pi) and sin(sym(pi,'r')) also return zero
```

Only the last one will be fully cancelled out of an expression, thus simplifying it.

Comment: To be exact you should use `sym('pi')` where PI is passed as a symbolic expression to be evaluated by the underlying MuPAD engine. When you pass a numeric input to `sym`, a certain amount of round-off error is involved in converting floating-point numbers (read the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html#inputarg_flag) regarding the `sym(num,flag)` form). By default, `sym(pi)` is equivalent to `sym(pi,'r')`, this "rational" form is adequate for expressions involving pi. If you try the other forms (`sym(pi,'d')`, `sym(pi,'e')`, `sym(pi,'f')`) you'd get different approximations